# Cart Price Rules - discount on certain number of products

Tags: cart, price, promotions, rules

i am new in Magento, i want to to add discount on certain number of products.
I mean, i have products on my store, every product has SKU.
I want to make discount 50% for purchasing 12 products on my site.
So the number 12 should be in the cart, no matter if it's 12 pieces of one product, or several products with a total of 12 pieces.

Comment: You can set it throught cart price rule. Marketing->Cartprice rule in condition  set total Items Qty as per the requirment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to Magento Admin and GoTo **Marketing** > **Cart Price Rules** and create a new rule by clicking **Add New Rule**

**Now you can set the condition**

See below screenshots
https://prnt.sc/1vpk1b3

**Set the discount Percentage**

See below screenshots
https://prnt.sc/1vpk6ki